# lightbox and colorbox script not working in woocomerce template

Tags: wordpress

I am using woocomerce theme, in that I have created a template and I have used popup in that template. But popup is not working on that template, where as other WP template working with popup.

Comment: Required reading:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try to debug your code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about lightbox popup of a product, you need to have a prettyPhoto enabled. If it's disabled for some reason, try putting this code in your functions.php file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lightbox' );
function lightbox() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prettyPhoto', $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), $woocommerce->version, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init', $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/prettyPhoto/jquery.prettyPhoto.init' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), $woocommerce->version, true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css', $woocommerce->plugin_url() . '/assets/css/prettyPhoto.css' );
    }
}
```

However, you also need to have prettyPhoto enabled on those images, that is, the anchors of images must have

`data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]"` inside.

And it's not really clear if this is what you mean. Be more clear in your question.